# Confusing clone passing down argument

Tags: c++, casting, arguments, clone, type-conversion

So basically I am solving the famous "Philosopher dining" problem, 5 philosopher is generating out using clone. The point is I want each philosopher to hold a id (from 0 to 4). I plan to do it using clone passing down argument. Here is the code (I omit some sub function)

```
void philoshopher(void* arg)
{
    int i = &arg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        printf("Philosopher %d is thinking", i);
        take_forks(i);
        printf("Philosopher %d is eating", i);
        sleep(2);
        put_forks(i);
     }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int a[N] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    void* arg;
    /*
    struct clone_args args[N];
    void* arg = (void*)args;
    */

    if (sem_init(&mutex, 1, 1) < 0)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {   if (sem_init(&p[i], 1, 1) < 0)
        {
            perror(NULL);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int  (*philosopher[N])() ;
    void * stack;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if ((stack = malloc(STACKSIZE)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memorry allocation error");
            return 1;
        }
        int c = clone(philosopher, stack+STACKSIZE-1, CLONE_VM|SIGCHLD, &a[i]);
        if (c<0)
        {
            perror(NULL);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //Wait for all children to terminate 
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compile out, I get this error:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘clone’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
expected ‘int (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘int (**)()’
```

I also try to cast this to a void pointer but still same result:

```
void* arg;
....
arg = (void*)(a[i]);
int c = clone(...., arg);
```

Anyone know how to fix this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't declaring your function pointer correctly.  It should look like this:

```
int  (*philosopher[N])(void*);
```

Basically when you're declaring function pointers you have to specify the argument type, because pointers to functions that accept different types are (thankfully!) incompatible with each other.

I think you also need to remove the & before a[i] in the function call.  That's giving you a pointer to a function pointer, and it just expects a plain function pointer apparently.

Comment: I change the phrase but it still give out the same error. Not sure why @@

Comment: @thomasdang see my new edit, I think I spotted another problem.